# Visual studio 2022 pro for JavaScript files the right click option "go to definition" does not automatically open the file like it used to in vs 2019

Tags: javascript, ide, definition

In Visual Studio 2022 pro for JavaScript files the right click option "go to definition" does not automatically open the file like it used to in VS 2019.

Any ideas how to get this feature back?

Comment: SO is a Q&A site for programming questions. It is not a place to ask questions about how to use a program.

Comment: So if I added the visual studio json setting file it would be a programming question then ... come on just mark it up.

Comment: @Jacob Visual Studio is a program primarily used by programmers, and as such questions about using Visual Studio **are** on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I found the answer: it's the ignore source file option